# Format json date

Tags: java, json

*Hi all,*

I'm getting my data onto webservice, but I'm having some trouble with the JSON data that is returned for Date data types. Basically, the string back that looks like this:

`/Date(1154970000000+0700)/`

How can i format it  to dd/mm/yyyy in java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you Google it, you will find a lot of implementations to parse it in Java.

[just have a look at one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ISO8601dateparsingutility.htm)
Other than that u can also use this - -

```
var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
```

I don't know if i could help u out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to format a .Net JSON date string. But it's not so clear whether you want to use Java or JavaScript. Suppose you are going to use Java, here is something you can try:

```
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormatDate 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String date = "/Date(1154970000000+0700)/".replaceAll("/Date\\((-?\\d+).*$","$1");
        String zone = "/Date(1154970000000+0700)/".replaceAll("/Date\\(-?\\d+([+-].*?)\\)/$","$1");
        long ldate = Long.parseLong(date);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println ("Local "+TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()+" Date: "+df.format(new Date(ldate)));
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"+zone));
        System.out.println ("Parsed Zone GMT"+zone+" Date: "+df.format(new Date(ldate)));
    }
}
```

Output on my computer(Timezone Eastern Standard Time):

```
Local Eastern Standard Time Date: 07/08/2006
Parsed Zone GMT+0700 Date: 08/08/2006
```

If you are looking for a Javascript solution, something like this will help:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var jsonDate = "/Date(1154970000000+0700)/";
      var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+).*/i, "new Date($1)"));
      var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;//convert timezone offset to milliseconds
      offset += 7*3600*1000;//convert to actual time zone 
      date = new Date(date.getTime()+offset);
      var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;         
      if(mm<10) mm = '0'+mm;
      var dd = date.getDate();
      if(dd<10) dd = '0'+dd;
      var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
      var date_str = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
      document.write(date_str + " GMT+700");
 </script>
```

**Note:** The argument passed to a Date object is a milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

If you want to know the ids of the timezone with the offset 7, you can use:

```
   String[] ids = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(1000*3600*7);
   System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(ids));
```

Output:

```
[Antarctica/Davis, Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Asia/Hovd, Asia/Jakarta, Asia
/Krasnoyarsk, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Asia/Pontianak, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Vientiane, Etc/
GMT-7, Indian/Christmas, VST]
```

**Update:** There is a **sign** difference between the JavaScript Date.getTimezoneOffset() and the Java TimeZone.getRawOffset() or TimeZone.getOffset(long ldate) methods. The JavaScript method getTimezoneOffset() and the Java method getOffset() have both taken into account the differences introduced by local timezone DST.